# Inverse of function $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inverse

I'm really confused right now, does there exist an inverse $f^{-1}$ to the function $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2-1$. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: Note that $f^{-1}(a)=\{\mathbf{x}\mid f(\mathbf{x})=a\}$. Here $f^{-1}$ denotes the inverse image.

Comment: So if I have $Z = f^{-1}(0) = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | f(x,y,z) = 0\}$ and I know that $Z = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x^2+y^2 = 1\}$, how would I get my $f$ and my $f^{-1}$?

Comment: Isn't $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2-1$, then? That's why I asked myself whether or not the inverse exists.

Comment: @MJP The inverse doesn't exists. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $f(1,-1,0)=f(-1,1,0)$. So, $f$ is not one-to-one and hence cannot be invertible.

Comment: Thanks. But if the inverse doesn't exist, how should I solve: "Describe the cylinder-surface $Z$ as a level set of a function $f$ such that: $Z = f^{-1} = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | f(x,y,z) = 0\}$?" Did I just find the wrong function?

Comment: No. You chose a correct function. The misunderstanding begin with the notation. The set what did you write describe a level set which can also be written as     
$$\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{R}^3:\, f(x,y,z)=0\}=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{R}^3:\, f(x,y,z)\in\{0\}\}=f^{-1}(\{0\})$$ where $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is the *inverse image* of $\{0\}$. In general, if you have a function $f:A\to B$ and $C\subseteq B$, the inverse image of $C$ is the set $$f^{-1}(C)=\{a\in A:\, f(a)\in C\}$$